# Input must be a string MATLAB ERROR when using cellstr(sentiment)

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

My sentiment variable is  cell class put when I try parse it to the cellstr fucntion it throws the following error...

> > cellstr(sentiment)
> >     Error using cellstr (line 32)
> >     Input must be a string.

I am trying to use the unique command but it throws this error...
Error using cell/unique (line 85)
Input A must be a cell array of strings.

When I open the variable there is a single column with sentiments positive, negative, neutral but it looks like each cell has a sub-cell. Could this be a reason for the errors? If so how would I correct this ?

I take a cell array that contains some unnecessary characters so i filter out for the relevant word using:

```
for i= 1:length(sentdate)
s=sentiment{i};
sentiment{i}={s(15:22)};

s2=date{i};
date{i}={s2(17:26)};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to show your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the curly brackets around whatever you're assigning into a cell.  The assignment is exactly symmetric to reading out the value:

```
s = sentiment{i};
sentiment{i} = s(15:22);
```

Surrounding a value with `{}` actually creates a cell array, which is why you appear to have a subcell.  To help understand this difference between `()` and `{}`, try this:

```
sentiment(i) = {s(15:22)};
```

Same result!  By using `()` to index sentiment, we're not dereferencing the cell contents.  So then the value to be assigned must itself be a cell.